# How to execute Python script from Java code in Android

Tags: android, jython, kivy, sl4a, qpython

I'm trying to make an standard Android application execute a python script that could return values to Java, but I'm facing a lot of issues.

Jython doesnt support this in the Android environment, SL4A is a dead project, Kivi seems to be an full stack framework that do not use Java at all and QPython is SL4A that works on Android 5+ but almost don't have documentation.

I wanted something like:

```
// From INSIDE my Java Code
new PythonEngine().execute('a = 1 + 1').getInt('a')
```

With QPython I found an example that executes an arbitrary code, but I couldn't figure how to get the outcome and how to run the script without opening a new activity that waits for user input to come back.

Is that possible? The example can be found here [QPython Java Sample](https://github.com/qpython-android/AndroidApp-with-qpython-API/blob/master/src/org/qpython/sample/MainActivity.java)

Comment: You could look at how kivy's build tools (python-for-android) work. Kivy on android works by having a java bootstrap app run the python code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any of thoses projects will help. For example, Kivy drive the Python execution, even it it's started from Java.

If you have an application in Java, but want to start a Python Interpreter, i guess solution using https://code.google.com/p/android-python27/ might be a start. Unsure if they have a Java interface in top of the Python C-API.