# How to execute Python codes from Java code in Android Studio?

Tags: java, python, azure, android-studio

I am building an Android application in Android studio with Java. I want to use Speech to text and Text to speech and some Machine Learning based python programs that I had already written.
Is it possible to do this? What is the technology stack that I need to accomplish this?

I came across various solutions like using sl4A, Jython, QPython and running the python code on the server.I have also gone through the following but I haven't found a solution yet

[Execute python script from android App in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34235763/execute-python-script-from-android-app-in-java)

[How to execute Python script from Java code in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917832/how-to-execute-python-script-from-java-code-in-android)

[Execute python script from android App in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34235763/execute-python-script-from-android-app-in-java)

Please explain with an example. As an example if I want to use the following python code (Speech to Text conversion using Google Speech recognition API) to run in my android app:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as src:
    print("speak....")
    audio = r.listen(src, 2)
    print("over")
try:
    print("you said: "+r.recognize_google(audio))
except:
    print("cannot recognize")
```

What steps am I supposed to follow? What is the best way to achieve it?
Thank you in advance.

EDIT 1: Can it be achieved using **azure services**?

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [JEP](https://github.com/ninia/jep) as a bridge between java and python, I've never actually tried this on android apps, only webapps. (in the FAQS of the project they state that it *could* work)

```
private RunOutputModel run(RunInputModel model, String path) throws Exception {

    RunOutputModel retVal = new RunOutputModel();

    try (SharedInterpreter jep = new SharedInterpreter()) {
        jep.eval("import sys");
        jep.eval("sys.path.append('" + path + "')");
        jep.eval("import master_main");
        jep.set("well", model.getWell());
        jep.set("startDate", model.getStartDate());
        jep.set("endDate", model.getEndDate());
        //other vars
        jep.eval("objClass = master_main.master()");
        jep.eval("x = objClass.main(path, well, startDate, endDate,/*vars*/)");
        Object result1 = jep.getValue("x");
        //manager result
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        retVal.setStatus(e.getMessage());
        Utils.log("error", e.getMessage(), path);
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

And here's python:

```
class master:
def __init__(self):
    self.SETVARIABLES = ''

def main(self, path, well, startDate, endDate):
    #stuff
```

By searching I've found [this](https://github.com/chaquo/), they even have project examples of mixed source code app (both python and java).

Comment: Thank you so much but chaquopy as you mentioned in the link has its unlicensed running for only 5 minutes after which we need to reinstall it.